# expose a service oData or Rest with excel?

Tags: excel, rest, odata

Maybe what I'm going to ask is crazy, but it's what they're asking me and I don't know if it can be done.

Is it possible to expose a service oData or Rest with excel? For example, excel is listening to a request and answered the sum of 2 numbers.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that Questions asking to suggest a product are usually discouraged as they attract highly opinionated responses!

While possible, without compatible infrastructure it is usually easier to create your own API, *it can still use an Excel workbook as a backend* using techniques commonly referred to as *Excel Automation*.

- One MS example: [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c)

As part of requirements gathering, as this is a very specific request you should ask them to produce at least a set of the queries and the expected URL format that they intend to use.

- A request like this usually means they are coming across from an existing platform or they are trying to copy the functionality from another provider/competitor

MS have a general solution for this called [Excel Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api) that allows you to upload workbooks to SharePoint Services and query against them, the idea is that now you can have a single source of "truth", effectively a *live* workbook without passing around copies of it.

> **NOTE:**
> The Excel Services REST API applies to SharePoint and SharePoint 2016 on-premises. For Office 365 Education, Business, and Enterprise accounts, use the Excel REST APIs that are part of the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) endpoint.

The other MS offering that can create a REST interface for Excel is [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/power-bi-overview), [basic instruction on how to upload an offline workbook to Power BI can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-excel-workbook-files#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20use%20a%20local%20Excel%20file,get%20a%20notification%20that%20the%20workbook%20is%20ready.)

---

I'm offering this advice because I have fielded this type of request from management or clients in the past, it is important to help them fully understand their reasons behind the request before proceeding as there can be significant licensing and setup costs compared to implementing a custom API manually